# ¿Cuál es el antónimo de analfabetismo - analfabeta?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, antónimos

En el [diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=alfabeta) se define alfabeto/a como:

> adj/sust. Ho, ES, Ni, CR, Cu, RD, Co, Ec, Bo, Py, Ur. Referido a persona, que sabe leer y escribir. cult → esm.

Si bien cubre un buen espacio del mundo hispano, deja afuera a zonas como Argentina, España o México, entre otros. Por otro lado el término [alfabetismo](https://dle.rae.es/alfabetismo?m=form) en el DLE se explica como:

> Arg., Bol., C. Rica, Ec., El Salv., Hond., Méx., Nic., Pan., Perú, R. Dom., Ur. y Ven. Conocimiento básico de la lectura y la escritura. *El índice de alfabetismo es elevado en la región.*

Este término ya aplica para casi toda Hispanoamérica, sin embargo, en particular no aplican para España. pensaba en *[Letrado](https://dle.rae.es/letrado?m=form)* como sinónimo de *Alfabeto*, por lo visto está en desuso y los significados actuales no serían los apropiados (Numeración en romanos pues la lista no permite saltar de 2 al 6)

> I. adj. Sabio, docto o instruido.
>
> II. adj. coloq. Que presume de discreto y habla mucho y sin fundamento. (...)
>
> VI. m. y f. abogado (‖ licenciado en derecho).

Así pues, ¿Cuáles pueden ser los antónimos más apropiados en otras zonas diferentes a las mencionadas (sería mas hacia Chile, Guatemala, Guinea Ecuatorial, España y Puerto Rico) para analfabeto y analfabetismo?

Comment: Se me ocurre _ilustración_ como antónimo de _analfabetismo_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No hay que irse muy lejos de la palabra raíz para encontrar un término para España.

[**alfabetizado**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=alfabetizado)

> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que sabe leer y escribir

Quizás este adjetivo en si no se emplea mucho, pero el término "grado de **alfabetización**" sí.

También se usa el siguiente, que aparece en tu análisis inicial de **letrado**

**[instruido](https://dle.rae.es/?w=instruido)**

> 1. adj. Que tiene buen caudal de conocimientos adquiridos.

Como apunta @Gustavson, *para el segundo adjetivo, tenemos la frase nominal "nivel de **instrucción**".*

Comment: Para el segundo adjetivo, tenemos la frase nominal "nivel de instrucción".

Comment: El término *instruido* no me convence del todo, quizá porque la lectura no es el único modo de adquirir conocimientos (por ejemplo, las recetas de familia, gran parte de las leyendas, mitos o narraciones suelen ser parte del conocimiento oral de un pueblo). Por tanto, me quedaría  con alfabetizado o algún otro término

Comment: @VeAqui Si no va acompañado de algún complemento, "instruido" suele asociarse a "que ha recibido instrucción pública", siendo la mínima instrucción pública, saber leer y escribir. "Es una persona instruida" sin más, no suele aplicarse a los elementos que mencionas. "Está instruido en recetas de la abuela" no me parece una frase natural.